# How to fill up vector or array with JSON c++

Tags: c++, curl, osrm

Please help me to fill up a vectors or arrays from CURL request via Json responce.

I have a responce from a OSRM website (u can see it below)/ That is a JSON format, but i can not parse it and use in my code later. I do not understand how to do it.
Can anyone help me?

> > {"tracepoints":
> >     [
> >     {"location":[73.103166,49.817488],"name":"some street1","hint":"10UDgP___k=","matchings_index":0,"waypoint_index":0,"alternatives_count":0},
> >           {"location":[73.104389,49.817199],"name":"some street2","hint":"xUUDgP___k=","matchings_index":0,"waypoint_index":1,"alternatives_count":0},
> >           {"location":[73.108378,49.815211],"name":"some street3","hint":"-EUDgP___k=","matchings_index":0,"waypoint_index":2,"alternatives_count":0}
> >       ], "matchings":
> >
> > [ {
> >     "distance":480.5,"duration":31.6,"weight":31.6,"weight_name":"routability","geometry":"i~`oHy}d}Lx@sF|A_K|@gFpFuD","confidence":0.579856,"legs":
> >     [{"distance":93.5,"duration":6.2,"weight":6.2,"summary":"","steps":[]},{"distance":387,"duration":25.4,"weight":25.4,"summary":"","steps":[]}]
> >     }
> >     ],
> >     "code":"Ok"}

I downloaded a https://github.com/nlohmann/json but i am not able to use it.
Please gimme something to solve a problem.
My VS2015 code below

```
    #pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
    #pragma comment(lib, "wldap32.lib")
    #pragma comment(lib, "Normaliz.lib")
    #pragma comment(lib, "crypt32.lib")

    #define CURL_STATICLIB

    #ifdef _DEBUG
    #   pragma comment (lib, "curl/libcurl_a_Debug.lib")
    #   pragma comment (lib, "curl/libssl_Debug.lib")
    #   pragma comment (lib, "curl/libcrypto_Debug.lib")
    #else
    #   pragma comment (lib, "curl/libcurl_a_Release.lib")
    #endif // DEBUG _DEBUG

    #include "curl\curl.h"

    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include "iostream"
    #include "string"
    #include <iomanip>


    #include "nlohmann/json.hpp"
    using json = nlohmann::json;


    static int writer(char *data, size_t size, size_t nmemb, std::string *writerData)
    {
        if (writerData == NULL)
            return 0;

        writerData->append(data, size*nmemb);

        return size * nmemb;
    }


    int main()
    {
        json JStruct ;
        std::string content;

        //std::cout << "Some_Text";

        std::vector<double> myLatpoints;
        std::vector<double> myLonpoints;

        curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
        CURL *curl = nullptr;
        curl = curl_easy_init();
        curl_global_cleanup();
        if (curl)
        {
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://127.0.0.1:5000/match/v1/driving/73.103130,49.817423;73.104353,49.817137;73.10824,49.81517");
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &content);
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, writer);
            CURLcode code = curl_easy_perform(curl);
            curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        }
        //curl_global_cleanup();

        JStruct = content;

        // HELP ME TO FILL UP MY VECTORS HERE PLEASE


        std::cin.get()  ;
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: I suggest you using external libraries to manipulate JSON in C++. I used jsonpp and it was ok.

Comment: have you tried using json::parse(content)?

Comment: Then you can access each attrib using get. From the project README j["address"].get<std::string>()